# Page height is not still same

Tags: javascript, browser

I have problem with my project. I need to detect page height and add this height as parameter to to url. It's working fine. But when I try it in browser and try to refresh page few times, sometime happens that size is a bit less then before. Is possible to solve it?

```
<script>
    var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight) + 40;
    document.location.href += "#" + height;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the `asynchroniously` behaviour of `JavaScript`. I guess some elements are not yet loaded (not always) when your script is executed - and due to the missing element(s) the height differs.

To prevent this you should execute your code after `document` was loaded.

```
(function() {
  var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
  var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight) + 40;
  document.location.href += "#" + height;
})();
```

or using jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement;
  var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight) + 40;
  document.location.href += "#" + height;
});
```